# Ubuntu 18.04 chrome appindicator

Tags: unity, google-chrome, icons, indicator

does someone know how to make the chrome tray icon appear in the top bar
[just like this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQQ2n.png)

I can't get it to work, the only icons that appear there for me, are Teams and OBS .

[Here are my extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnwjs.png)

I also tried to start chrome with " env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity " , same thing .

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using the default Ubuntu desktop or are you using Unity? By 18.04, we started using an Ubuntu theme version of Gnome Shell instead of Unity by default. You can install the Unity desktop but it's no longer the standard. Also, Unity appindicators can work on Gnome Shell but I believe you need a Gnome Shell extension to make it work.

Comment: I'm using the default ubuntu desktop, but I tried everything I found, yet none of them worked

Comment: Have you tried the "dash to panel" gnome shell extension?

Comment: The reason I ask about this extension is because this post on reddit (unrelated problem) shows an indicator for Chrome on their panel (top bar) using the dash to panel gnome shell extension.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome force closes when you close the window
I have tried using icon hider but I doubt that this GNOME extension will help you but you can try if you want to